# Is there a way to make calculations with list items within a sum?

Tags: python, sum, calculator

I'm trying to write a program that calculates the standard deviation of measurements in my physics class. The function takes a list and an average, and it needs to work like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkJPg.jpg). The code throws out the error "float is not iterable" when i try it this way because of the sum, but without the sum i only get the last result of the calculation, not the actual result.

```
def deviate(argument):
  for item in argument:
    result = math.sqrt((1/(len(argument) - 1)) * sum((item - average)**2))
  return result

print(deviate(list_in))
```

Comment: Where does `average` come from? Seems like you want the average without computing it. You say "The function takes a list and an average", but the actual function you show only takes one argument, the `list`. Similarly, the formula in your image is not being faithfully replicated here (the square root covers the result of the sum multiplied by `1/n`, but you only apply it to the unchanging `1/n`). You need to compute some things up front, some in a loop, and others at the end, you can't just blindly throw code at a single line and hope.

Comment: No i actually calculate the average beforehand, just didnt add the codeblock. And the average is a float fyi. But thank you for that information about the square root, will try to fix that...

Comment: You need to provide a true [MCVE] (ideally, something we could directly copy into a tool like [TIO](http://tio.run/#python3) and see your problem). We can't guess at what is and is not there when you give us code that doesn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Side-note: If you don't need to reinvent the wheel (you're solving problems, not writing code that must itself be submitted for a grade), just [use the `statistics` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html), e.g. `pstdev`.

Comment: Yeah thats true, did not think of that before, i'm sorry. And regarding the statistics module: i tried that one, but it actually calculates the deviation with 1/n and not 1/n-1... That's why i tried to create my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image you shared, plus the code you provided, this method using list comprehension to compute the sum looks equivalent - I can't test it though without an example input and output:

```
import statistics

def deviate(argument):
    n = len(argument)
    average = statistics.mean(argument)
    return math.sqrt((1 / (n - 1)) * sum([((item - average) ** 2.0) for item in argument]))
```

Comment: Wow great, thank you very much sir, it works as intended! Cheers. Will definetly learn from that one

Comment: @TomW. if you want anything explained further let me know.